# How to upgrade version of CXXABI in libstdc++.so.6

Tags: upgrade, gcc

I'm currently trying to run a Python program using RDKit and am facing some errors. I was debating whether to post this on Stack Overflow or here, but doing some research gave me the feeling that this is a bit more related to Ubuntu's `libstdc++`.

The problem is that whenever I try to import a Python package, I get the error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /home/user1/anaconda3/envs/user1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdkit/DataStructs/../../../../libRDKitDataStructs.so.1)
```

I've done a bit of research and managed to do the following:

I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to `/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/` since this is where my `libstdc++.so.6` is located. After that I kept getting the "could not find `CXXABI_1.3.11` which is required version" error, and so did:

```
strings /home/user1/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

which outputs:

```
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_FLOAT128
```

I'm assuming that in order for the original program to run properly, I need to be seeing `CXXABI_1.3.11` when I run the `strings` command as I did.

Does anybody know how I might be able to upgrade the version here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run this using Anaconda's python, or the system's python? The *system's* libstdc++.so.6 is somewhere like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and likely supports `CXXABI_1.3.11` already (at least it does on 18.04). If you're trying to run it via Anaconda, then presumably it's Anaconda that you need to update.

Comment: @steeldriver I am in a similar situation. Updating Anaconda did not help.